# Align text in the table

Tags: tables

I have a following table:

```
\def \p {\circle*{7}}
\def \s {$\bullet$}
\def \j {\circle{7}}
\def \m {$\circ$}
\def \n {$\otimes$}

\begin{table}[h]
 \centering
\small
\def\arraystretch{1.05}
\rotatebox{90}{%
   \begin{tabular}[b]{|l|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}\hline
Aplikace&\rotatebox{270}{Elektrická energie s~časovým posunem}&\rotatebox{270}{Kapacita elektrické dodávky}&\rotatebox{270}{Zatížení}&\rotatebox{270}{Oblast regulace}&\rotatebox{270}{Rezervovaná kapacita dodávky}&\rotatebox{270}{Napěťová podpora$^1$}&\rotatebox{270}{Transientní přetížení$^1$}&\rotatebox{270}{Odložení přenos. a distrib. obnovy$^1$}&\rotatebox{270}{Doba využití energie -- nákladový management$^1$}&\rotatebox{270}{Poptávaný výkon$^1$}&\rotatebox{270}{Elektrická spolehlivost$^1$}&\rotatebox{270}{Kvalita energie$^1$}&\rotatebox{270}{OZE -- časový posun dodávky}&\rotatebox{270}{Kapacita OZE -- zpevnění}&\rotatebox{270}{Integrace větrných el.}\\
\hline
Elektrická energie s~časovým posunem&&\p&\s&\j$^\ast$&\s&\p&\p$^\dagger$&\p$^\dagger$&\n&\n&\n&\n&\s&\s&\j \\ \hline
Kapacita elektrické dodávky&\p&&\s$^\ast$&\j$^\ast$&\s$^\ast$&\p&\s$^\dagger$&\p$^\dagger$&\n&\n&\n&\n&\j$^{X\ast}$&\j$^{X\ast}$&\n \\ \hline
Zatížení&\s&\s$^\ast$&&\j$^\ast$&\s$^\ast$&\s&\j$^X$&\s$^{X\ast}$&\j$^{\ast \ddagger}$&\j$^{\ast \ddagger}$&\n&\n&\j&\n&\n \\ \hline
Oblast regulace&\j$^\ast$&\j$^\ast$&\j$^\ast$&&\j$^\ast$&\n&\j$^{X\ast}$&\n&\n&\n&\n&\n&\m&\m&\n \\ \hline
Rezervovaná kapacita dodávky&\s&\s$^\ast$&\s$^\ast$&\j$^\ast$&&\p&\j$^\ast$&\s$^\ast$&\s$^{\ast \ddagger}$&\s$^{\ast  \ddagger}$&\n&\n&\j$^{\ast}$&\j$^{\ast}$&\m$^{\ast}$\\ \hline
Napěťová podpora$^1$&\p&\p&\s&\n&\p&&\s&\p&\s$^\ddagger$&\s$^\ddagger$&\s$^\ddagger$&\s$^\ddagger$&\s$^{\diamond\ddagger}$&\s$^{\diamond\ddagger}$&\n \\ \hline
Transitní přetížení$^1$&\p$^\dagger$&\s$^\dagger$&\j$^X$&\j$^{X\ast}$&\j$^\ast$&\s&&\s$^{X\ast}$&\j$^{\ast}$&\j$^{\ast}$&\m&\n&\s$^\diamond$&\s$^{\dagger}$&\n \\ \hline
Odložení přenos. a distrib. obnovy$^1$&\p$^\dagger$&\p$^\dagger$&\s$^{X\ast}$&\n&\s$^\ast$&\p&\s$^{X\ast}$&&\s$^{\ast}$&\s$^{\ast}$&\m&\n&\s$^\diamond$&\s$^{\dagger}$&\n \\ \hline
Doba využití energie -- nákladový management$^1$&\n&\n&\j$^{\ast \ddagger}$&\n&\s$^{\ast \ddagger}$&\s$^{\ddagger}$&\s$^{\dagger}$&\s$^{\dagger}$&&\p$^{\dagger}$&\p&\p&\s$^{\diamond}$&\s$^{\diamond \dagger}$&\n \\ \hline
Poptávaný výkon$^1$&\n&\n&\j$^{\ast \ddagger}$&\n&\s$^{\ast \ddagger}$&\s$^{\ddagger}$&\s$^{\dagger}$&\s$^{\dagger}$&\p$^{\dagger}$&&\p&\p&\s$^{\diamond}$&\p$^{\diamond \dagger}$&\n \\ \hline
Elektrická spolehlivost$^1$&\n&\n&\n&\n&\n&\s$^{\ddagger}$&\m&\m&\p&\p&&\p&\s$^{\diamond}$&\s$^{\diamond}$&\n \\ \hline
Kvalita energie$^1$&\n&\n&\n&\n&\n&\s$^{\ddagger}$&\n&\n&\p&\p&\p&&\n&\n&\n \\ \hline
OZE -- časový posun dodávky&\s&\j$^{X\ast}$&\j&\m&\j$^{\ast}$&\s$^{\diamond \ddagger}$&\s$^{\diamond}$&\s$^{\diamond}$&\s$^{\diamond}$&\s$^{\diamond}$&\s$^{\diamond}$&\n&&\p&\j$^{X}$ \\ \hline
Kapacita OZE -- zpevnění&\s&\s$^{X\ast}$&\n&\m&\j$^{\ast}$&\s$^{\diamond \ddagger}$&\s$^{\dagger}$&\s$^{\dagger}$&\s$^{\dagger\diamond}$&\p$^{\dagger\diamond}$&\s$^{\diamond}$&\n&\p&&\j$^X$ \\ \hline
Integrace větrných el.&\j&\n&\n&\n&\m$^\ast$&\n&\n&\n&\n&\n&\n&\n&\j$^X$&\j$^X$& \\
\hline \hline
\multicolumn{16}{|c|}{
{\p} -- excelentní \; \s -- dobrý \; \j -- ucházející \; \m -- nepříliš vhodný \; \n -- nekompatibilní}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}}
\caption{Aplikační synergická matice \cite{eyer2010}}
\label{tab-aplik}
\end{table}
```

[image]

And now I would like to align the text "Apliace" in the first table cell to the bottom of baseline.

How can I do it?

Comment: Please post something that is compilable, ia such that we do not have to guess, but can just copy it to our systems and try to help.

Comment: And try to keep it minimal.

Answer (score 1):

You could insert the following instructions in the preamble

```
\newlength\mylen
\settowidth\mylen{Doba využití energie -- nákladový management$^1$}
\addtolength\mylen{-2\baselineskip}  % subtract 2\baselineskip
```

where `Doba využití energie -- nákladový management$^1$` is the longest line in the table's header row.

Then, write

```
\raisebox{-\mylen}{Aplikace}
```

instead of just `Aplikace` in the table itself. The string `Aplikace` will be "pushed down" down by the amount stored in `\mylen`; it works out to about 185pt if the basic document font size is 10pt.

[image]